# oracle: update a column with not null value

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanna update a column of a table:

```
UPDATE product prod 
SET    prod.prod_supplier_id = (SELECT s.prod_supplier_id 
                                FROM   supplier s 
                                WHERE  s.prodno = prod.prodno
                             )
```

the `SELECT s.prod_supplier_id 
                                    FROM   supplier s 
                                    WHERE  s.prodno = prod.prodno`

mustn't return a null result, if it's null, the update will not be made
How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to filter the rows to be updated in the WHERE clause as well:

```
UPDATE product prod 
SET    prod.prod_supplier_id = (SELECT s.prod_supplier_id 
                                FROM   supplier s 
                                WHERE  s.prodno = prod.prodno
                             ) 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 42 
              FROM   supplier s2 
              WHERE  s2.prodno = prod.prodno);
```

It *might* be faster using a `MERGE` (assuming `prodno` is the primary key in `product`):

```
merge into product 
using
(
   select p.prodno,
          s.prod_supplier_id
   from product p
     join supplier s on s.prodno = p.prodno  
) t on (t.prodno = prod.prodno)
when matched then update
   set prod_supplier_id = t.prod_supplier_id;
```

**Not tested!**

Answer (score 1):

first of all create a back up table:

```
CREATE TABLE productBAK AS SELECT * FROM product;
```

now you can use update query like this:

```
UPDATE product prod 
SET    prod.prod_supplier_id = (SELECT s.prod_supplier_id 
                            FROM   supplier s 
                            WHERE  s.prodno = prod.prodno and
                            s.prod_supplier_id is not null
                         ) 
WHERE prod.prodno in (SELECT s1.prodno FROM supplier s1 where s1.prod_supplier_id is not null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause specifies which record or records that should be updated. If you omit the WHERE clause, all records will be updated!

Answer (score 0):

I see prod_supplier_id being a column in both product and supplier.

Can you explain in which table the prod_supplier_id must not be null?
Looking at your query you want something like

```
update product
set prod_supplier_id = (select prod_supplier_id 
                        from supplier 
                        where prod_supplier_id is not null);
```

Issues you're facing:

- all product records will be updated with the same prod_supplier_id
- if the subselect statement returns more than one record -let's say you have 5 suppliers, so 5 prod_supplier_id's, the update statement will fail.

Can you tell us:

- do you want all your products to be set to 1 supplier?
- if not, do you have a list of which product should have which supplier?

R

Comment: Could you paste the output of

the statements DESC PRODUCT and DESC SUPPLIER

so we can see table structure?

Comment: the prod_supplier_id  is the primary key of the table supplier

Comment: Hi Neila, 

could you post the output of

    DESC PRODUCT
and

    DESC SUPPLIER

please?

Also, do you store the product id's in the supplier table?

Comment: I store the product number in the table supplier, each supplier has one product.
when I get many products, if a product has a supplier I wanna set its id(the supplier_id) in the table product, but I don't wanna make extra updates cause I have a trigger which will insert in another table when the table product is updated,
just I wanna get the supplier_id after verifying the where condition, if there is a result I ll update the table if its null, I ll not make an extra update to set a null resukt

Comment: ok, it's a bit unconventional how your datamodel is set up. I would expect that you stored product information in your product table, including a supplier_id and fill the supplier table with supplier information, without a product_id column in the supplier table.

when you set your tables up like that, you will have a 1-to-many relationship between supplier and product.
1 supplier can reference many products, while the other way around, one product will allways be linked to one supplier

Maybe you should read a bit about normalisation :-)